# Collect values as I recurse tree in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, search, tree

I understand basic recursion, but this problem has be stumped. I have a tree structure set up in a database, where each node(row) has an id and parent id.

I need a function that can run and in the callback return an array of all the descendants of a particular node given its id.

I've been able to put together a function that can print out all of the values, but I can't figure out how to capture them and return them in the callback. I know the base case isn't set up correctly, as I'm not sure what it should even be.

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you!

```js
// My "database"
var nodes_collection = [
  {id:"id1",name:"name1",parentid:"."},
  {id:"id2",name:"name2",parentid:"id1"},
  {id:"id3",name:"name3",parentid:"id1"},
  {id:"id4",name:"name4",parentid:"id2"},
  {id:"id5",name:"name5",parentid:"id3"},
  {id:"id6",name:"name6",parentid:"id3"},
  {id:"id7",name:"name7",parentid:"id5"},
  {id:"id8",name:"name8",parentid:"id7"},
  {id:"id9",name:"name9",parentid:"id7"},
  {id:"id10",name:"name10",parentid:"id9"},
  ];


// This is NOT a real function, it simply performs the function that the real getChildren does when connected to my database!!!
function getChildren(parentid, callback){
 
 var children = [];
 for(var i=0; i < nodes_collection.length; i++){
  if(nodes_collection[i].parentid == parentid){
   children.push(nodes_collection[i].id);
  }
 }
 callback(children);
 
}



function allDescendants(parentid, callback) {
  getChildren(parentid, function(childNodes) {
    if (false) { // Only false because I don't know what my base case should be.
      //console.log("done");
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = childNodes[i];
        allDescendants(child);
        console.log(child); // Here it prints out all the values. How can I capture them? and return them with my callback?
      }
    }
  });
}


allDescendants("id3", function(result){
 console.log(result);
});
```

EDIT:

**Due to some confusion, I've changed the code to a bare bones example of what I'm trying to do that can be run locally** !!! getChildren() is **NOT** a real function, it simply performs the function that the real getChildren does when connected to my database!!!

Bottom line:
The code in question works to recursively touch all values. Now how can I store all the values that are currently being outputted via console.log()?

Comment: can you also put the array sent by the database?

Comment: @AboubacarOuattara yes, I've added an example.

Comment: Could you please amend your example to work, as you say, "printing "out all of the values?"

Comment: The code now works locally. @גלעדברקן

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one simple way. We create a result object and an intermediary recursive function, keeping allDescendants as a wrapper. When the recursion is complete, we return the result that now has all the descendants.

JsvaScript code:

```js
// My "database"
var nodes_collection = [
  {id:"id1",name:"name1",parentid:"."},
  {id:"id2",name:"name2",parentid:"id1"},
  {id:"id3",name:"name3",parentid:"id1"},
  {id:"id4",name:"name4",parentid:"id2"},
  {id:"id5",name:"name5",parentid:"id3"},
  {id:"id6",name:"name6",parentid:"id3"},
  {id:"id7",name:"name7",parentid:"id5"},
  {id:"id8",name:"name8",parentid:"id7"},
  {id:"id9",name:"name9",parentid:"id7"},
  {id:"id10",name:"name10",parentid:"id9"},
  ];


// This is NOT a real function, it simply performs the function that the real getChildren does when connected to my database!!!
function getChildren(parentid, callback){
 
 var children = [];
 for(var i=0; i < nodes_collection.length; i++){
  if(nodes_collection[i].parentid == parentid){
   children.push(nodes_collection[i].id);
  }
 }
 callback(children);
 
}



function allDescendants(parentid, callback) {
  let result = [];
  
  let go = function(children){
    for (child of children){
      result.push(child);
      getChildren(child, go)
    }
  }
  
  getChildren(parentid, go);
  
  callback(result);
}


allDescendants("id3", function(result){
 console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this:

```
let obj = [
      {id:"id1",name:"name1",parentid:"."},
            {id:"id2",name:"name2",parentid:"id1"},
            {id:"id3",name:"name3",parentid:"id1"},
            {id:"id4",name:"name4",parentid:"id2"},
            {id:"id5",name:"name5",parentid:"id3"},
]

function getChilds(obj, parent_id, callback) {

   if(obj.length === 0) return;

   else if (typeof callback !== 'function'){
    throw new Error("The callback must be a function ");
    return;
   }

   let childs = obj.filter(function (c) {return c.parentid == parent_id })

   if(childs.length > 0 ){
    childs = childs.map(function (c) {return c.id})   
   }

   callback(childs)

}
// Test
getChilds(obj, "id1", function (childs) {console.log(childs)})
```

Comment: This works for single level trees, but there's no recursion here. The function fails to find nodes 4 and 5. This same thing could be achieved by simply querying the database for all object with parentid=x

Comment: can you post a complex table with multiple nodes sent by your database?

Comment: Yes, I've posted a revised example with a deeper tree structure.